# Should employees get promotion as soon as they show some higher qualities?

Tags: germany, promotion

I work as a test automation engineer at a software company in Germany.

Recently, I asked for a promotion after 3.5 years, but my request was turned down because my manager thinks I haven't been ***"consistently"*** meeting certain criteria. I was said, all is fine by me, but i just need to keep doing the same and they might consider my promotion again at 6 month or 1 year.

The data indicates that my performance in 2023 was better than many others, but my boss wants to ensure that I can maintain this level of performance. In other words, I believe he doesn't trust that I'll continue to perform at this high level after a promotion, so he wants me to stay in my current position for a longer period.

My question is:

1. Should managers promote employees as soon as they show another level of qualities ?
2. If the problem stopping my promotion is trust, what can I do to make it better?

Comment: "If the problem stopping my promotion is trust, what can I do to make it better?" is there anything wrong with the obvious and universal: find a job that will pay what you think you deserve? Or is that something you won't consider for some reasons?

Comment: i am happy in this company, but i just feel i am not growing in my career-path. So,do you think, trust-issue cannot be solved and it is better to leave ?

Comment: Is trust that worries you or the lack of actual promotion? Like, if you were to nail this down, where you can flip a magic one and solve one problem, but only one, what would it be?

Comment: Companies should promote employees according to their own policies, procedures, economic circumstances and needs, including the need to motivate and retain staff. As such, this is looking for company-specific advice, which nobody here can give you. And as to what the policies/procedures should be, that's opinion-based, so would also be off topic here.

Comment: @Jimmy What determines whether an answer to this question is "right" or "wrong"? To me, each company gets to decide themselves. I've certainly seen lots of companies doing it differently

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul honestly, lack of promotion. i don't care if my boss does not trust me, because i know, i have done my best.

Comment: @Jimmy Well, then this is the same question as many are asked here every week: what do I do when I am not feeling valued enough at current company? You go and look for a better company. I highly recommend to research that question, we have many great answers for it.

Comment: What are you expecting from a promotion? More money? Different job title?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on exactly what you mean by "promotion".

If "promotion" means a new role with new responsibilities, then the timing of that has a lot of other considerations for the company, as you'll be doing new work, and (presumably) not doing some of the work that you used to do before. So a company can only promote you when there's space for you to move into that new role, and the role you used to do can be filled by someone else.

But if "promotion" means adjusting your job title and compensation to match the work that you're *already doing*, then that should be done as soon as the company is confident that you are able to perform effectively in that job.

Because otherwise they're effectively paying you a junior's salary to do a more senior role - which is obviously in their interest, but very not much not in yours. And if they keep it up for too long, then you may find another company that's willing to pay you what you're worth.

---

In your specific instance, I would be asking for some clear defined targets *in writing*. So if you manage to achieve X over the next Y months, then you'll get the promotion you want. Because it's very easy to get strung along by a company that keeps promising you a promotion in future, without being willing to commit to anything firm.

And if they're not willing to do that and are just hoping to take advantage of you, then I would be considering whether this company is the right place for you, or whether you can leverage those 3.5 years experience to find a more senior job elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> Should managers promote employees as soon as they show another level of qualities ?

In general **no** - which isn't to say there aren't exceptions, e.g. where the need for someone in the promoted position is urgent or there's significant risk of losing an already valuable employee.

Promotions aren't something that's easy to "undo" - so if you promote someone who can't handle the new position and they struggle you're probably going to lose someone who was actually valuable in their non-promoted role. If you promote someone based on a good performance and they then decide to coast you're stuck with an under-performer who is probably costing you more than they did before for less.

> If the problem stopping my promotion is trust, what can I do to make it better?

Well, it sounds as though your manager has been pretty clear - if you want to be promoted then keep doing what you've been doing (i.e. performing highly).

The above not withstanding, you do have options. Sustained good performance over a year is actually a pretty decent length of time already and you aren't being crazy to look for potential promotion as a result. This isn't a case where you've smashed it out of the park for a month and asked for a promotion, since your manager has said they want to see more from you it's perfectly reasonable to put a firm timeframe on that. Ask him if the question can be revisited in, say, six months. It gives you time to demonstrate a continued level of performance, them time to prepare for a potential promotion (budgeting, potential hiring to replace you etc).

What's more, doing that puts gentle but definite pressure on them (and by extension the company) that you're serious about this and infers that should you meet the criteria over that time and they decline you *again* it's going to be riskier for them. Because repeatedly declining promotions or raises when the worker is meeting the criteria, performing well etc. brings with it a strong subtext of "your extra effort/performance isn't making the difference" and that leads to people either leaving or taking the proverbial foot off the gas.

The alternative of course is to polish up the CV and see what's out there for you - quick leaps up the career ladder are often the easiest to accomplish by moving employer at the same time. The best thing about that is there's nothing to stop you doing *both* options in parallel. If the current employer comes through with a promotion before you find the role you want elsewhere, you win! If the job search turns up a great role that gives you what you want first, you win!

Answer (score 1):

"Should" scenarios do not track with reality.  The sooner that you divorce yourself with this notion, the less stress you'll encounter in your life when "should" doesn't work out.

In this case, you believe in [meritocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meritocracy), where you'd reap rewards based on your talent.  Here in the US, such an idea really doesn't work in IT jobs.  It's often easier to get another job to make more money than it is to stay in the same job hoping for a raise.  Meritocracy costs the company money!  It also encourages a culture of competition instead of a culture of collaboration -- the two are diametrically opposed.

At the end of the day, if you're a consistent high performer and you know your worth, you can't expect everyone else to appreciate it in the same way, and have to take ownership in a way that *you* see fit.

Comment: I would say that meritocracy doesn't have to be diametrically opposed to collaboration. If the qualities valued in the meritocracy include collaboration than it can work together.  It's up to the employer to inform you of what they value and build from there.

Comment: @cdkMoose Meritocracy means that people focus on efforts that will make them more visible and diminish others at the same time.   They keep vital company information in silos, and purposely don't share as a means of retaining power.  With collaboration, people can't do all this.  The meritocracy approach is VERY common in the entertainment industry. - it's dog-eat-dog

Comment: That's your view.  Good companies make collaboration a clear value to the company and include that in evaluation of your performance and therefore your "score" on the meritocracy scale.  It doesn't have to be dog-eat-dog unless people make it that way.